# Get date when a xml was created NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, ipad, nsxmlparser

I am having a pretty big xml file (17 MB) on a webserver, which is constantly updated (once or twice a month). I take the XML and parse it to Core data, when the user triggers an update. Now I want to check during my Apps wake/start up if the locally parsed database is up to date or if there is a newer xml on the server.

The xml is created by a non-IT-company via MS Office, so I can't really expect them to do many changes to the xml. right now i only have the

```
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="someXML.xsd" generated="2012-06-28T12:53:12">
```

generated Attribute of dataroot.

Any tips on how to get the date the file was created in a fast and neat way?

Comment: Can you ask them to add a tag of "LastupDatedDate" in the xml file?

Comment: There is no information in the HTTP headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have am giving you the important code. I am taking a string variable in .h file and initializing the string in parse didstartelement method of parsing. Check the below code.

```
 @interface TestViewController: UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>  {
        NSString *generatedDate;
    }
    @end

#import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"dataroot"] ) {
        generatedDate = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[[attributeDict objectForKey:@"generated"] retain]];
        }
   }
@end
```

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping there would be a way to read the date from some file description or header file. But this is fast enough when I abort the parser after the dataroot-tag was found. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just store and check the created or modified date on the server and compare it to a value you have stored? That way if it is the same you don't even need to bother to read the XML.
You could get a false positive (date changed but data hasn't), but you wouldn't get a false negative (data changed but date hasn't), so it would cut down a lot of processing.

Once you have decided it has changed you can either pass the XML to check for the date, of if it is in a specific place of the file (ie, the beginning), just read that much of the file and search for the string

Answer (score 0):

you can get your generated time using NSXMPParser. use following

```
NSXMLParser *parser  = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:yourXMLData];

[parser setDelegate:self];

[parser parse];
```

This will call your delegate methods. You need to handle following delegate method to get your date

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
     NSString *generatedDate = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"generated"];
}
```

Hope this helps